# Count number of pages in large set of pdf files : Out of memory

Tags: perl, pdf

I'm trying to get the total number of pages in a large set of PDF files (300.000). The script I wrote works but errors out with an 'Out of memory'. In TaskManager I see memory usage grow gradually.

Is this standard behavior of the File::Find? Does anyone have an alternative approach?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Find;
use PDF::API2;

$totalpages = 0;

sub pagesPDF {
  return unless -f; 
  my $fullpath = $File::Find::name;
  my $pdf = PDF::API2->open($fullpath);
  my $pages = $pdf->pages;
  $totalpages += $pages;      
}

find (\&pagesPDF, "G:/MYDIR/1");


print "Total pages of pdf pages = $totalpages\n";
```

Comment: is there a 'close' method?

Comment: @reto I've looked in specs of PDF::API2. There does not seem to be a close method.

Comment: Have you tested if `$pdf->end()` deletes the file? I know it states to destroy the document, not the object, but that would actually surprise me. Why would there be a method that specifically destroys pdf documents? I would assume it to actually cleanly destroy the object, hopefully properly closing the file.

Comment: @DeVadder Thats seems to fix it. Probably files where kept open. Job has been running for an hour now and no growth in memory usage. PDF's are not deleted. Documentation is somewhat confusing on this. Please make it an answer so I can give you the credits and for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the documentation is a little oddly formulated here.
`$pdf->end()` seems to not destroy the document as stated but to properly destroy the object and thereby close the document.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, it may help:

```
sub pagesPDF {
  return unless -f; 
  my $fullpath = $File::Find::name;
  my $pdf = PDF::API2->open($fullpath);
  my $pages = $pdf->pages;
  $totalpages += $pages; 
  undef $pdf;     
}
```

Or you could us a different approach:

```
sub pagesPDF {
  return unless -f; 
  my $fullpath = $File::Find::name;
  my $pages = `/usr/bin/pdfinfo $fullpath | grep 'Pages:'| cut -f2- -d":"`;
  $pages =~ s!\D+!!gis;
  $totalpages += $pages;      
}
```

Comment: That second version really sounds like the most save approach.

Comment: `undef $pdf` is not likely to be useful here – when the lexical `$pdf` variable goes out of scope at the end of the subroutine, the object's refcount will drop to zero, and be destroyed. Manually removing the reference with `undef` has the same effect, so it should only be used on global variables, or when you need to free something before the scope is left. Neither is the case here.